# ui-router move from nestedState to another parentState

Tags: angular-ui-router

I can't seem to navigate directly from parentA.childState to parentB state.  How does one do this in one move?

```
$stateProvider.state(
    'parentA',
    {
        url: '/parentA',
        template: '<p>Parent A <ui-view /></p>',
        controller: function() {}
    }
).state(
    'parentA.childState',
    {
        url: '/childA',
        template: '<span>Child A</span>',
        controller: function(){}
    }
).state(
    'parentB',
    {
        url: '/parentB',
        template: '<span>Parent B</span>',
        controller: function(){}
    }
);
```

Assume my application currently at state parentA.childState and then I click the link below which SHOULD take me to parentB state.

```
<a ui-sref="parentB">Link only goes back to parentA state</a>
```

How can I go directly to parentB state?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  What I'm asking for here is default behavior.  It should work like this out of the box.  My problem was my own code interrupting this redirect.